# ¿Existe "decoupage" en español?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, francés

Según Wikipedia:

> El término **decoupage** (o **découpage**) tiene su origen en la palabra francesa *découper*, que significa recortar. Se trata de una técnica manual decorativa en la que se emplean papeles impresos o telas para pegar sobre soportes varios como madera, cerámicos, metales, velas, jabones, vidrios, lozas y cartón entre otros.
>
> <sub>[wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupage)</sub>

Sin embargo, el término (ni *decoupage* ni *découpage*) aparece recogido en el DRAE.

Entonces, una de dos

a) El término existe y se usa, pero no está recogido en el DRAE

b) Esta entrada de Wikipedia se confunde (quizá está mal editada. La [entrada en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupage) propone los mismos nombres para esta técnica) y no existe realmente ese término en español.

¿Existe el término "decoupage" en español?

Comment: No entiendo esta pregunta. ¿Existe alguna alternativa en español para esta técnica? Porque, si no lo hay, la alternativa b) no me parece que tenga mucho sentido.

Comment: Parece que se usa pero muy poco. En el CREA aparecen menos de una decena de resultados, y la mitad son de un libro sobre cine. En el CORPES XXI aparecen también menos de diez resultados. No sé si habrá alguna alternativa.

Comment: Decoupage and collage aren't the same.  Collage: you may prepare the objects to be thrown together in a variety of ways, most often by tearing.  You may also use found objects.  The idea is to make an assemblage of those objects.  There is generally a somewhat spontaneous, improvised feel to it.  Decoupage: first of all, it doesn't have that feel to it.  Originally it used scissors, but now the term has evolved a bit, and you even see it used to describe a particular type of film editing.  You could think of it as fancy scissors work, though.  I think that recently...

Comment: ... decoupage has gotten a bit mired in precisely cutting out shapes and gluing them to objects.  // There was a wonderful French children's film in the late 90's that was all in black and white, animated based on intricate cut-outs.  I wish I could remember the title or even what it was about.  But it was one of those few and far between works of art that really do change the way one sees the world. I think my older son was about 4 and found it too sad. // I think you can probably use the term in Spanish but you just have to do some googling to see how people use it in practice in Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El término no se encuentra (aún) en la RAE pero parece que la palabra es entendida en español. Wordreference tiene una entrada en el diccionario inglés->español:

> [**decoupage, découpage** *n*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=decoupage) | découpage *nm*
>
> *French* (art of varnished collage) | (*voz francesa*) collage barnizado *nm* + *adj*

Y se da un ejemplo de uso:

> hacer un découpage *loc verb*

Cómo se puede ver, una de las propuestas es "collage barnizado". Pero los términos decoupage o découpage son también usados:

- [El Arte del decoupage](https://www.cervantes.com/libro/9788492678501/arte-del-decoupage-el/)
- [Decoupage (Nueva Artesanía)](https://www.amazon.es/Decoupage-Nueva-Artesan%C3%ADa-Maggie-Pryce/dp/8466230149/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0/259-1946253-9147330?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=36T0MP9CCJ1T569FG76K)
- [Curso de Decoupage](http://www.estudiodeartesantiago.com/curso-de-decoupage/)
- [El découpage: qué es, para qué sirve y cómo aplicarlo](http://www.materialparamanualidades.es/blog/el-decoupage-que-es-para-que-sirve-y-como-aplicarlo/)

Es decir, en mi opinión la respuesta es:

a) El término existe y se usa, pero no está recogido en el DRAE